# Relation between Beauville-Bogomolov form and Intersection Product on Hilbert scheme of K3 surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, k3-surfaces, holomorphic-symplectic

I am learning about Hilbert scheme of points $S^{[n]}$ on projective K3 surfaces S. Since these are hyperkähler varieties, the second cohomology $H^2(S^{[n]},\mathbb{Z})$ is endowed with the non-degenerate Beauville-Bogomolov form $q$.

Moreover, we know that the Picard group $Pic(S^{[n]})$ is isomorphic to $Pic(S) \oplus \mathbb{Z} \frac{E}{2}$, where $E$ is the exceptional divisor of the Hilbert-Chow morphism.

The Picard group of $S$ is endowed with the usual intersection pairing. I wondered if there is a relation between the intersection number of two line bundles $L \cdot L'$ and the Beauville-Bogomolov pairing $q(L_n, L_n')$, where $L_n$ resp. $L_n'$ denotes the corresponding line bundle on $S^{[n]}$.

Comment: Yes, the decomposition you wrote down is orthogonal with respect to the BB-form. So a class $D=aL+b(E/2)$ with $L\in Pic(S)$ has BB-square equal to $a^2L^2-2b^2$.

Comment: Thanks very much! Do you have any reference, where I can read up on this?

Comment: Yes, https://www.math.nyu.edu/~tschinke/papers/yuri/09curvetable/curvetable11.pdf or https://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.4071.pdf